# How do I create a new FCPDF instance using Laravel with UTF

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, fpdf

In original one there's functionality

```
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
```

But I am using that one created for Laravel (https://packagist.org/packages/elibyy/tcpdf-laravel)

And there is nearly no docs so I have no way of doing it. Does anyone have any idea how to achieve it?

**How can i set default pdf charset to pdf?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a **tcpdf.php** file on your `/config/` folder in your app, there you can set some configuration details like this:

```
<?php
return [
    'page_format'           => 'A4',
    'page_orientation'      => 'P',
    'page_units'            => 'mm',
    'unicode'               => true,
    'encoding'              => 'UTF-8', // <- Your desired encoding <-
    'font_directory'        => '',
    'image_directory'       => '',
    'tcpdf_throw_exception' => false,
];
```

In case your configuration file don't exists, as the [docs](https://packagist.org/packages/elibyy/tcpdf-laravel) says you can create it doing:

> Laravel-TCPDF comes with some basic configuration. If you want to
>   override the defaults, you can publish the config, like so:
>
> ```
> php artisan vendor:publish
> ```
>
> Now access **config/tcpdf.php** to customize.

Comment: the config file won't be available unless he publishes them. You should add a note to run `php artisan vendor:publish`

Comment: @Sandeesh Just I added it now :p

Comment: Great answer. Thank you very much